# Why is an allocator allowed to override the ctors and dtors of its value_type?

Tags: c++

As far as I know, containers are supposed to use `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` and `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy` which are either `Alloc::construct` and `Alloc::destroy` respectively or `value_type::value_type` and `value_type::~value_type` (the defaults).

Why allow an allocator to override the default ctor and dtor of its `value_type`? When is it useful?

Comment: You could log the construction and destruction of elements, or notify some other component of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This allows the allocator to construct objects in custom ways.

An example based on standard library features is the `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` which will pass an allocator to any objects it constructs (as long as they support construction from allocators). That is useful when you want all elements of a container to use the same allocator as the container itself. When the container's allocator constructs an element it passes itself (or a copy of itself rebound to  the element type) to the element.

Another example is if you have huge vectors of a trivial type like `double` but you don't want to pay the cost of zero-initializing all the vector elements if you're going to re-assign them new values anyway. You can have a custom allocator that does nothing in its `construct` function, so that the elements are left uninitialized when the vector is resized.